# How do you decode an Ethernet Frame without things like Wireshark?

Tags: protocols, decode, ethernet

For example: How would one decode the following ethernet frame?

00 26 b9 e8 7e f1 00 12 f2 21 da 00 08 00 45 00 05 dc e3 cd 20 10 35 06 25 eb 0a 0a 0a 02 c0 a8 01 03 c3 9e 0f 40 00 00 10 00 00 00 14 00 70 10 00 5c 59 99 00 00 02 04 05 b4 01 03 03 06 00 00 01 98 64 34 e8 90 84 98 20 12 18 19 04 85 80 00

I know that the first 6 bytes are the MAC destination address : 00 26 b9 e8 7e f1 The next 6 bytes are the source MAC address : 00 12 f2 21 da 00 The next 2 bytes show the ethernet type : 08 00 The next 4 bytes are : 45 00... Ipv4... "5" the number of bytes in the header.. and "00" means there are no differentiated services.

What I don't know is what anything after that is or how to read it.

Anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

Rearranging a bit your packet, we have:

```
00 26 b9 e8 7e f1 00 12  f2 21 da 00 08 00 45 00
05 dc e3 cd 20 10 35 06  25 eb 0a 0a 0a 02 c0 a8
01 03 c3 9e 0f 40 00 00  10 00 00 00 14 00 70 10
00 5c 59 99 00 00 02 04  05 b4 01 03 03 06 00 00
01 98 64 34 e8 90 84 98  20 12 18 19 04 85 80 00
```

If you ***know*** that the first 6 octets form the destination mac address, that means that it is an Ethernet layer 2 packet.

According to IEEE 802.3, $3.1.1:

1. First 6 octets are the destination mac address (`00 26 b9 e8 7e f1`)
2. Next 6 octets are the source mac address (`00 12 f2 21 da 00`)
3. Next 4 octets are, **optionally** the 802.1Q tag (present, `08 00 45 00`)
4. Next 2 octets are either:

   - Maximum payload size - aka MTU (if <= 1500, which is the case, `05 dc` is 1500)
   - Ethernet 2 frame (if >= 1536)
5. Next is the payload ranging from 46 octets (if the 802.1Q tag is absent) or 42 octets (if the 802.1Q tag is present) to up to 1500 octets (starts at `e3 cd 20 10 ...`, ends either at `20 12 18 19` or at `03 06 00 00`, depends on the 7th item)
6. Last 4 octets form the CRC32 code (either `01 98 64 34` or `04 85 80 00`, depending on the 7th item)
7. There is also 12 octets used for padding (random - not so random - bytes), that may or may not be inserted in this packet. (if inserted, the padding is `e8 90 84 98 20 12 18 19 04 85 80 00`)

Comment: 3. optionally => how do you know that it is (3.) and not (4.)?

Comment: and 4. shouldnt this be ether type like IP or anything like this?

Comment: @ReeCube The IP goes in the internet layer, not the MAC layer

Comment: @ReeCube Even the Ethernet2 frame cannot be larger than 1,518 bytes. 0x800 is 2048, which is greater than that, meaning that it cannot be the payload size.